# Why is the ng-click handler being fired twice?

Tags: angularjs

I've got a button that's used to delete a question:

```
<a class="btn-small float-right" data-ng-click="deleteQuestion(question)">
  <i data-ng-class="{true: 'icon-step-backward', false: 'icon-remove'}
  [question.IsDeleted]"></i>
</a>
```

This is the code behind the button:

```
$scope.deleteQuestion = function (data) {
  if (data.IsDeleted) {
      data.IsDeleted = false;
      for (var i = 0; i < deletedQuestions.length; i++) {
          if (deletedQuestions[i] == data) {
              deletedQuestions.splice(i, 1);
          }
      }  
  } else {
      data.IsDeleted = true;
      if ($.inArray(data, deletedQuestions) === -1) {
          deletedQuestions.push(data);
      }
  }
};
```

Now when I press the button I noticed the function has been fired twice.
The first time it deletes the question, the second time it undoes that action.

What I want was one button to delete a question and when you click it again, it undoes that action.

I'm just wondering what I've overlooked...

**EDIT** Here is a fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/rquackenbush/AbWKs/

Comment: could you share fiddle

Comment: Does it change if you add an `href="#"` to your link? (that just a wild guess.)

Comment: I shared a fiddle that replicates this behavior

Comment: Well, I know what the problem is in my fiddle - I'm calling angular.bootstrap(document, ["myApp"]).  If I remove that, everything works fine and I don't get the double invocations.

Comment: Due to my routing, adding href="#" is not an option.
Thanks for the fiddle RQDQ, I've checked it out and noticed the same thing when deleting angular.bootstrap. I'll go and check it out on my app now.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found out what the problem was.

The link is inside a list:

```
<li class="question-item"
   data-app-bind-html="question.template">                        
       <a class="btn-small float-right" data-ng-click="deleteQuestion(question)">
         <i data-ng-class="{true: 'icon-step-backward', false: 'icon-remove'} [question.IsDeleted]">
         </i>
      </a>
<li>
```

I've made an data-app-bind-html which binds a html part inside it. This caused the link to be bound twice, which made it fire twice too.
To solve this I just made sure the directive binds the html part and not the whole listitem.